# Facing IndexError: tuple index out of range in vanilla example for Petals by bigscience-workshop

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

To get bootstrapped, I tried to use the example from Readme

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from petals import AutoDistributedModelForCausalLM
import torch 

# Choose any model available at https://health.petals.dev
model_name = "petals-team/StableBeluga2"  # This one is fine-tuned Llama 2 (70B)

# Connect to a distributed network hosting model layers
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoDistributedModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, torch_dtype=torch.float32)

# Run the model as if it were on your computer
inputs = tokenizer("A cat sat", return_tensors="pt")["input_ids"]
outputs = model.generate(input_ids=inputs, max_new_tokens=256)
print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0]))  # A cat sat on a mat...
```

The torch_dtype=torch.float32 was added due to CPU support warning but apart from that rest is the same as the original example yet I am facing the error and unable to complete the inference.

```
Oct 25 10:24:45.837 [INFO] Using DHT prefix: StableBeluga2-hf
Oct 25 10:25:02.883 [INFO] Route found: 0:40 via .VNxGn => 40:80 via _pHfajj
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jazz/codews/scripts/petals_test.py",line14,in<module>
outputs = model.generate(input_ids=inputs,
max_new_tokens=256)
へへへへへへへへへへへへへへへへへへへ
File "/home/jazz/miniconda3/envs/petals/lib/python3.11/site-packages/petals/client/remote_generation.py",line116,ingenerate
result = super () .generate (inputs,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^へへへへへへへへ
*ar9s, **киал!
**kwargs)
File "/home/jazz/miniconda3/envs/petals/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py",line115,indecorate_context
return func(*args,
**kwargs)
File "/home/jazz/miniconda3/envs/petals/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py",line1647,ingenerate
return selt-greedy searcht
File "/home/jazz/miniconda3/envs/petals/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py",line2492,ingreedy_search
model_inputs = selt.prepare inputs for generation(input ids,
File"/home/jazz/miniconda3/envs/petals/lib/python3.11/site-packages/petals/client/remote_generation.py",line37,inprepare_inputs_for_generation
return super prepare inputs _for _generation (input_ids.
**kwargs)
File"/home/jazz/miniconda3/envs/petals/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py",line1084,inprepare_inputs_for_generation
past_length = past key values [0] [0]. shape [2]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

OS : Ubuntu 22.04
CPU : i7-7700K
GPU: Nvidia 1070

Please guide me if I am missing something here.

I was expecting this to perform the inference but instead i gives Tuple error.

I validate that generate function from Hugging Face library need input_ids so input seems to be straight forward but yet it fails as per error snapshot above.

Comment: Please post the error as the text not the screenshot.

Comment: Updated error as code block